# Any good sources for using Apache-cxf/jax-rs to pass an object to a rest service? Looking for help

Tags: java, cxf, jax-rs

I am currently passing an object to my Apache CXF Rest client and it is not getting through.
Relevant stack trace below:

```
cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message. at cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:xxx)
at cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:yyy)
at cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.doChainedInvocation(ClientProxyImpl.java:zzz)
at cxf.jaxrs.client.ClientProxyImpl.invoke(ClientProxyImpl.java:qqq)
```

Any suggestions of things to look into for this type of problem to trace into this or sources of reference information on what can go wrong with jax-rs?

Comment: Is that the whole stacktrace?

Comment: Is an exception thrown on the server as well? Or is this exception thrown in just making the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it, turns out I had an unresolved server in a configuration file.